# Angular2 Kendo get or read grid results after filter change

Tags: kendo-grid, angular5

I'm filtering data in Kendo Grid. I want read those data at .ts level.
I'm using dataStateChange event but I'm not getting filter records. Which event should I use for get filter data?

```
    <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="UI.GridData"
                [selectable]="true"
                [sortable]="true"
                [filterable]="true"
                (selectionChange)="UI.GridData_SelectionChanged($event)"
                (dataStateChange)="UI.dataStateChange($event)">

 public dataStateChange(event: DataStateChangeEvent) {

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(filterChange)="filterChange($event)"

 public filterChange(filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor) {       
        filterBy(GridData, filter);
      }
```